# Safe Cracking Australian Informatics Olympiad 2009 Intermediate

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

Hi recently I was trying out a problem from the AIO 2009 Intermediate.

The problem (rephrased) is:

There is a sequence of positive integers, each of which has been encrypted via a non-negative constant k (by adding k to each value in the sequence, and k has no bounds as long as the following bounds for a and b hold), to give a list of integers a. We are given a small subset of the original non-encrypted list, b, such that 2<=len(b)<=30 and 2<=len(a)<=100000. Given the two lists, a and b, write a function that returns the original non-encrypted list of integers.(All integers in a and b satisfy 1< a,b<1000000). It is assured that there will only be one unique solution.

Some ideas that I considered are:

Brute force all the possible combinations of b until we find one that is a subset of a. (Time complexity of my solution is too high though (O(n^2)), if someone can code an O(n) solution it would work)

Finding the difference between the numbers in b and a, and then finding a matching subset. We then use this to find the index which b[0] corresponds to then derive the key k. (This works except that there are corner cases which I am unable to solve)

I was wondering if anyone could code a solution to this in python 3.x using either of these two methods. Furthermore, could you also explain which method would be better and more efficient, and why?

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean to encrypted? xor'ed? What are the bounds of k and the original integers? What to do if multiple solutions are possible?

Comment: @kfx I have edited the question, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are given the following list of "encrypted" integers:

```
E1 = [200,450,100,75,275,500,600,400,300]
```

And the decrypted sublist. Something like the following:

```
L1 = [25,225,450,550,350]
```

Transform L1 into a new array, L2, such that every element is the difference between itself and the previous element. That is `L2[i] = L1[i] - L1[i-1]`. For L2[0], let it be zero.

```
L2 = [0,200,225,100,-200]
```

Drop the first element (`L2 = L2[1:]`)

```
L2 = [200,225,100,-200]
```

Now, do the same normalization to the encrypted list:

```
E2 = [250,-350,-25,200,225,100,-200,-100]
```

Now do a classic substring string search on the normalized lists to find the matching index where L2 starts in E2.

```
def findStartIndex(needle, haystack):
    j = 0
    while len(needle) < len(haystack[j:])
         if (needle == haystack[j:j+len(needle)]
             return j
         j = j + 1
    return -1

index = findStartIndex(L2, E2)
```

If the search above returns an integer value: `index` (in this case `3`):

Then the key `k` is simply:  `E1[index] - L1[0]`

In this example, `k` is `50`

Comment: I think I have a typo or two in the example arrays.  I'll correct later when I get more time tonight.

Comment: Updated and validated.